# Trying to get the values of all child nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

My XML Looks like this:

```
<names>
    <goodnames>
        <name>Alpha</name>
        <name>Beta</name>
    </goodnames>
    <badnames>
        <name>blabla</name>
    </badnames>
</names>
```

Now I am trying to get the value of all child nodes that belong to goodnames or badnames. The code I've tried so far is this:

```
var goodnames = from el in doc.Root.Elements("goodnames") select el.Element("name");
```

Unfortunately, this only returns the very first element, in this case Alpha. However, I'd like to get all the name elements.

Comment: `select el.Element**s**("name");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all names you need to do this:

```
var allNames =
    from e in doc.Root.Descendants("name")
    select e.Value;
```

If you only want good names or bad names, try this kind of thing:

```
var goodnames =
    from el in doc.Root.Elements("goodnames")
    from n in el.Elements("name")
    select n.Value;
```

Comment: Thank you, your second suggestion was exactly what I was looking for.